# mapping SQL on a XML Hibernate

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

i'm creating some SQL Querys on XML and then read it with Hibernate and more shit :P 
and my problem is this:

-In my Query i have to use a "something < something" well, "<" is detected as a start of a tag in XML and i can't use that query, does anybody know how to do it?

here's the query:

```
<named-query name="Replacement.findByAmount">
        <query>select r from TReplacement r where r.having <= r.expected</query>
    </named-query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<query name="findByAmount">
        <![CDATA[select r from TReplacement r where r.having <= r.expected]]>
    </query>


Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findByAmount");
List results = query.list();
System.out.println("No of Results: " + results.size());
```

Comment: Thank you!! i'll try, i tell you in a moment if that works :D